# UDT as a parameter in EF4 query

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, sql-server-2008, entity-framework-4

I know that EF4 does not support User Defined *Table* Types (yet). I need to write a query, that accepts a list of pairs `<product_code, quantity>` and returns a record set with `product_code` and `price` for each `product_code` passed, based on `quantity`. What is my best option with EF4 to model this? The calculation in the database to get the price are quite complex, and there are a lot of products, which means that most of the action should happen server-side. (For example I can't get full list of prices from server first and then filter to the products I need on the client. I also can't apply quantity to the calculation on the client, that has to be passed to server and processed there). Any thoughts are welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you mostly answered your question. Computation must be done on the database server and you just want to get result, don't you? If you are using SQL Server 2008 you can create stored procedure which accepts [table valued parameter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510489.aspx). Now you can call this procedure either [directly using ADO.NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb675163.aspx) or using EF and `context.ExecuteStoreQuery` where you still pass `DataTable` to `SqlParameter` with `SqlDbType.Structured`.

If you don't use SQL Server 2008 you need stored procedure with one big nvarchar parameter passing whole list as comma delimited string. Your stored procedure will first [parse this list](http://vyaskn.tripod.com/passing_arrays_to_stored_procedures.htm) to temporary table and then process the computation in the same way as with table valued parameter.

Comment: I couldn't get your suggestion to work and have opened up another question to see if there is an answer.  Please see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8157345/entity-framework-stored-procedure-table-value-parameter