# Entity Framework Stored Procedure Table Value Parameter

Tags: c#, entity-framework, stored-procedures, ef-code-first, table-valued-parameters

I'm trying to call a stored procedure that accepts a table value parameter.  I know that this isn't directly supported in Entity Framework yet but from what I understand you can do it using the `ExecuteStoreQuery` command off of the `ObjectContext`.  I have a generic entity framework repository where I have the following `ExecuteStoredProcedure` method:

```
public IEnumerable<T> ExecuteStoredProcedure<T>(string procedureName, params object[] parameters)
{
    StringBuilder command = new StringBuilder();
    command.Append("EXEC ");
    command.Append(procedureName);
    command.Append(" ");

    // Add a placeholder for each parameter passed in
    for (int i = 0; i < parameters.Length; i++)
    {
        if (i > 0)
            command.Append(",");

        command.Append("{" + i + "}");
    }

    return this.context.ExecuteStoreQuery<T>(command.ToString(), parameters);
}
```

The command string ends up like this:

```
EXEC someStoredProcedureName {0},{1},{2},{3},{4},{5},{6},{7}
```

I tried to run this method on a stored procedure that accepts a table valued parameter and it breaks.  I read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6084061/udt-as-a-parameter-in-ef4-query) that the parameters needed to be of type `SqlParameter` and the table valued parameter needs to have the `SqlDbType` set to `Structured`.  So I did this and I get an error stating:

```
The table type parameter p6 must have a valid type name
```

So, I set the SqlParameter.TypeName to the name of the user defined type I created on the database and then when I run the query I get the following truly helpful error:

```
Incorrect syntax near '0'.
```

I can get the query to run if I revert back to ADO.NET and and execute a data reader but I was hoping to get it to work using the data context.

Is there a way to pass a table value parameter using `ExecuteStoreQuery`?  Also, I am actually using Entity Framework Code First and casting the `DbContext` to an `ObjectContext` to get the `ExecuteStoreQuery` method available.  Is this necessary or can I do this against the `DbContext` as well?

Comment: Seems it's not possible currently: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2837350/table-valued-parameter-in-stored-procedure-and-the-entity-framework-4-0

Comment: I was afraid of that but according to the following answer it appears it is possible although no example was given.  I left a comment with a link to this question to see if he would respond: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6084061/udt-as-a-parameter-in-ef4-query/6084728#6084728

Comment: did you get this to work in the end? are able to paste a full example?

Answer (score 103, accepted):

**UPDATE**

I've added support for this on Nuget Package - https://github.com/Fodsuk/EntityFrameworkExtras#nuget  (EF4,EF5,EF6)

Check out the [GitHub](https://github.com/Fodsuk/EntityFrameworkExtras) repository for code examples.

---

Slightly off question, but none the less useful for people trying to pass user-defined tables into a stored procedure. After playing around with Nick's example and other Stackoverflow posts, I came up with this:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var entities = new NewBusinessEntities();

        var dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Columns.Add("WarningCode");
        dt.Columns.Add("StatusID");
        dt.Columns.Add("DecisionID");
        dt.Columns.Add("Criticality");

        dt.Rows.Add("EO01", 9, 4, 0);
        dt.Rows.Add("EO00", 9, 4, 0);
        dt.Rows.Add("EO02", 9, 4, 0);

        var caseId = new SqlParameter("caseid", SqlDbType.Int);
        caseId.Value = 1;

        var userId = new SqlParameter("userid", SqlDbType.UniqueIdentifier);
        userId.Value = Guid.Parse("846454D9-DE72-4EF4-ABE2-16EC3710EA0F");

        var warnings = new SqlParameter("warnings", SqlDbType.Structured);
        warnings.Value= dt;
        warnings.TypeName = "dbo.udt_Warnings";

        entities.ExecuteStoredProcedure("usp_RaiseWarnings_rs", userId, warnings, caseId);
    }
}

public static class ObjectContextExt
{
    public static void ExecuteStoredProcedure(this ObjectContext context, string storedProcName, params object[] parameters)
    {
        string command = "EXEC " + storedProcName + " @caseid, @userid, @warnings";

        context.ExecuteStoreCommand(command, parameters);
    }
}
```

and the stored procedure looks like this:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_RaiseWarnings_rs]
    (@CaseID int, 
     @UserID uniqueidentifier = '846454D9-DE72-4EF4-ABE2-16EC3710EA0F', --Admin
     @Warnings dbo.udt_Warnings READONLY
)
AS
```

and the user-defined table looks like this:

```
CREATE TYPE [dbo].[udt_Warnings] AS TABLE(
    [WarningCode] [nvarchar](5) NULL,
    [StatusID] [int] NULL,
    [DecisionID] [int] NULL,
    [Criticality] [int] NULL DEFAULT ((0))
)
```

Constraints I found include:

1. The parameters you pass into `ExecuteStoreCommand` have to be in order with the parameters in your stored procedure
2. You have to pass every column in to your user-defined table, even if they are have defaults. So it seems i couldn't have a  IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL column on my UDT

Comment: This is exactly what we ended up doing.  Sorry I didn't update the post with the solution.  Thanks for taking time to do it! I have awarded you the correct answer.

Comment: Thanks, your question helped send me down the correct path :)

Comment: I'm not sure ssilas777, I would assume the underlying data access components of the DataContext are similar to either a DbContext or ObjectContext. I'll look at supporting this with the NuGet package i've put up on Nuget :)

Comment: was it Db context or entity context? can someone help me?

Comment: my example uses the ObjectContext, but this can be completed on the DbContext.Database object.

Comment: I think that it's the creation of the ado DataTable which seems to pollute the most.  See my answer below for creating/populating the table directly from your IEnumerable<T>

Comment: thats why i put that part of the work away into a nuget package, allowing you to do the easy bit :)  https://github.com/Fodsuk/EntityFrameworkExtras

Comment: Hello Mike, I was successfully able to invoke the SProc using your Nuget package.
However, not able to map the result set to a similar model using the generic ExecuteStoreProcedure<T> method. The collection is returned but all the properties are null. 
Would you be able to help?

Comment: Resolved it!
The TResult convention is to have setters instead of fields.
The following link was helpful.. thanks!
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ee358758(v=vs.100).aspx

Answer (score 23):

Okay, so here is a **2018 update**: end to end solution which describes how to invoke stored procedure with table parameter from Entity Framework ***without nuget packages***

I'm using EF 6.xx, SQL Server 2012 and VS2017

## 1. Your Table Value prameter

Let's say you have a simple table type defined like this (just one column)

```
go
create type GuidList as table (Id uniqueidentifier)
```

## 2. Your Stored procedure

and a stored procedure with several parameters like:

```
go
create procedure GenerateInvoice
    @listIds GuidList readonly,
    @createdBy uniqueidentifier,
    @success int out,
    @errorMessage nvarchar(max) out
as
begin
    set nocount on;

    begin try
    begin tran;  

    -- 
    -- Your logic goes here, let's say a cursor or something:
    -- 
    -- declare gInvoiceCursor cursor forward_only read_only for
    -- 
    -- bla bla bla
    --
    --  if (@brokenRecords > 0)
    --  begin
    --      RAISERROR(@message,16,1);
    --  end
    -- 


    -- All good!
    -- Bonne chance mon ami!

    select @success = 1
    select @errorMessage = ''

    end try
    begin catch  
        --if something happens let's be notified
        if @@trancount > 0 
        begin
            rollback tran;  
        end

        declare @errmsg nvarchar(max)
        set @errmsg =       
            (select 'ErrorNumber: ' + cast(error_number() as nvarchar(50))+
            'ErrorSeverity: ' + cast(error_severity() as nvarchar(50))+
            'ErrorState: ' + cast(error_state() as nvarchar(50))+
            'ErrorProcedure: ' + cast(error_procedure() as nvarchar(50))+
            'ErrorLine: ' + cast(error_number() as nvarchar(50))+
            'error_message: ' + cast(error_message() as nvarchar(4000))
            )
        --save it if needed

        print @errmsg

        select @success = 0
        select @errorMessage = @message

        return;
    end catch;

    --at this point we can commit everything
    if @@trancount > 0 
    begin
        commit tran;  
    end

end
go
```

## 3. SQL Code to use this stored procedure

In SQL you would use something like that:

```
declare @p3 dbo.GuidList
insert into @p3 values('f811b88a-bfad-49d9-b9b9-6a1d1a01c1e5')
exec sp_executesql N'exec GenerateInvoice @listIds, @CreatedBy, @success',N'@listIds [dbo].[GuidList] READONLY,@CreatedBy uniqueidentifier',@listIds=@p3,@CreatedBy='FFFFFFFF-FFFF-FFFF-FFFF-FFFFFFFFFFFF'
```

## 4. C# Code to use this stored procedure

And here is how you can call that Stored Procedure from Entity Framework (inside WebAPI):

```
    [HttpPost]
    [AuthorizeExtended(Roles = "User, Admin")]
    [Route("api/BillingToDo/GenerateInvoices")]
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> GenerateInvoices(BillingToDoGenerateInvoice model)
    {
        try
        {
            using (var db = new YOUREntities())
            {
                //Build your record
                var tableSchema = new List<SqlMetaData>(1)
                {
                    new SqlMetaData("Id", SqlDbType.UniqueIdentifier)
                }.ToArray();

                //And a table as a list of those records
                var table = new List<SqlDataRecord>();

                for (int i = 0; i < model.elements.Count; i++)
                {
                    var tableRow = new SqlDataRecord(tableSchema);
                    tableRow.SetGuid(0, model.elements[i]);
                    table.Add(tableRow);
                }

                //Parameters for your query
                SqlParameter[] parameters =
                {
                    new SqlParameter
                    {
                        SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Structured,
                        Direction = ParameterDirection.Input,
                        ParameterName = "listIds",
                        TypeName = "[dbo].[GuidList]", //Don't forget this one!
                        Value = table
                    },
                    new SqlParameter
                    {
                        SqlDbType = SqlDbType.UniqueIdentifier,
                        Direction = ParameterDirection.Input,
                        ParameterName = "createdBy",
                        Value = CurrentUser.Id
                    },
                    new SqlParameter
                    {
                        SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Int,
                        Direction = ParameterDirection.Output, // output!
                        ParameterName = "success"
                    },
                    new SqlParameter
                    {
                        SqlDbType = SqlDbType.NVarChar,
                        Size = -1,                             // "-1" equals "max"
                        Direction = ParameterDirection.Output, // output too!
                        ParameterName = "errorMessage"
                    }
                };

                //Do not forget to use "DoNotEnsureTransaction" because if you don't EF will start it's own transaction for your SP.
                //In that case you don't need internal transaction in DB or you must detect it with @@trancount and/or XACT_STATE() and change your logic
                await db.Database.ExecuteSqlCommandAsync(TransactionalBehavior.DoNotEnsureTransaction,
                    "exec GenerateInvoice @listIds, @createdBy, @success out, @errorMessage out", parameters);

                //reading output values:
                int retValue;
                if (parameters[2].Value != null && Int32.TryParse(parameters[2].Value.ToString(), out retValue))
                {
                    if (retValue == 1)
                    {
                        return Ok("Invoice generated successfully");
                    }
                }

                string retErrorMessage = parameters[3].Value?.ToString();

                return BadRequest(String.IsNullOrEmpty(retErrorMessage) ? "Invoice was not generated" : retErrorMessage);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            return BadRequest(e.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

I hope it helps!

Comment: the 2018 version is the 2012 nuget code pasted on stackoverflow :P

Answer (score 9):

I want to share my solution on this problem:

I have stored procedures with several table value parameters and I found out that if you call it this way:

```
var query = dbContext.ExecuteStoreQuery<T>(@"
EXECUTE [dbo].[StoredProcedure] @SomeParameter, @TableValueParameter1, @TableValueParameter2", spParameters[0], spParameters[1], spParameters[2]);
var list = query.ToList();
```

you get a list with no records.

But I played with it more and this line gave me an idea:

```
var query = dbContext.ExecuteStoreQuery<T>(@"
EXECUTE [dbo].[StoredProcedure] 'SomeParameterValue', @TableValueParameter1, @TableValueParameter2",  spParameters[1], spParameters[2]);
var list = query.ToList();
```

I changed my parameter **@SomeParameter** with its actual value **'SomeParameterValue'** in command text.
And it worked :)
This means that if we have something else than **SqlDbType.Structured** in our parameters it doesn't pass them all correctly and we get nothing.
We need to replace actual parameters with their values.

So, my solution looks as follows:

```
public static List<T> ExecuteStoredProcedure<T>(this ObjectContext dbContext, string storedProcedureName, params SqlParameter[] parameters)
{
    var spSignature = new StringBuilder();
    object[] spParameters;
    bool hasTableVariables = parameters.Any(p => p.SqlDbType == SqlDbType.Structured);

    spSignature.AppendFormat("EXECUTE {0}", storedProcedureName);
    var length = parameters.Count() - 1;

    if (hasTableVariables)
    {
        var tableValueParameters = new List<SqlParameter>();

        for (int i = 0; i < parameters.Count(); i++)
        {
            switch (parameters[i].SqlDbType)
            {
                case SqlDbType.Structured:
                    spSignature.AppendFormat(" @{0}", parameters[i].ParameterName);
                    tableValueParameters.Add(parameters[i]);
                    break;
                case SqlDbType.VarChar:
                case SqlDbType.Char:
                case SqlDbType.Text:
                case SqlDbType.NVarChar:
                case SqlDbType.NChar:
                case SqlDbType.NText:
                case SqlDbType.Xml:
                case SqlDbType.UniqueIdentifier:
                case SqlDbType.Time:
                case SqlDbType.Date:
                case SqlDbType.DateTime:
                case SqlDbType.DateTime2:
                case SqlDbType.DateTimeOffset:
                case SqlDbType.SmallDateTime:
                    // TODO: some magic here to avoid SQL injections
                    spSignature.AppendFormat(" '{0}'", parameters[i].Value.ToString());
                    break;
                default:
                    spSignature.AppendFormat(" {0}", parameters[i].Value.ToString());
                    break;
            }

            if (i != length) spSignature.Append(",");
        }
        spParameters = tableValueParameters.Cast<object>().ToArray();
    }
    else
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < parameters.Count(); i++)
        {
            spSignature.AppendFormat(" @{0}", parameters[i].ParameterName);
            if (i != length) spSignature.Append(",");
        }
        spParameters = parameters.Cast<object>().ToArray();
    }

    var query = dbContext.ExecuteStoreQuery<T>(spSignature.ToString(), spParameters);


    var list = query.ToList();
    return list;
}
```

The code surely could be more optimized but I hope this will help.

Comment: Uhh, isn't this vulnerable to sql injection?

Comment: @jag I left a TODO in the code so you can develop your own logic to overcome injections. also not sure if after 8 years this solution is still applicable

Answer (score 5):

```
var sqlp = new SqlParameter("@param3", my function to get datatable);
sqlp.SqlDbType = System.Data.SqlDbType.Structured;
sqlp.TypeName = "dbo.mytypename";

  var v = entitycontext.Database.SqlQuery<bool?>("exec [MyStorProc] @param1,@param2,@param3,@param4", new SqlParameter[]
                    {
                        new SqlParameter("@param1",value here),
                        new SqlParameter("@param2",value here),

                        sqlp,
                        new SqlParameter("@param4",value here)

                    }).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: Please add some context around the code and format the code.

Comment: you can just copy paste it. I'm new here, I dont know what you are telling.

Comment: What I mean is the code is not formatted well and why this will work in your opinion should be mentioned.

Comment: I don't know how to describe here. Actually the param3 needed to be declared as System.Data.SqlDbType.Structured;. So I initiate that out side the parameter declaration scope and used the variable in that scope.

Answer (score 2):

The DataTable approach is the only way, but constructing a DataTable and populating it manually is fugly.  I wanted to define my DataTable directly from my IEnumerable in a style similar to EF's fluent model builder thingy.  So:

```
var whatever = new[]
            {
                new
                {
                    Id = 1,
                    Name = "Bacon",
                    Foo = false
                },
                new
                {
                    Id = 2,
                    Name = "Sausage",
                    Foo = false
                },
                new
                {
                    Id = 3,
                    Name = "Egg",
                    Foo = false
                },
            };

            //use the ToDataTable extension method to populate an ado.net DataTable
            //from your IEnumerable<T> using the property definitions.
            //Note that if you want to pass the datatable to a Table-Valued-Parameter,
            //The order of the column definitions is significant.
            var dataTable = whatever.ToDataTable(
                whatever.Property(r=>r.Id).AsPrimaryKey().Named("item_id"),
                whatever.Property(r=>r.Name).AsOptional().Named("item_name"),
                whatever.Property(r=>r.Foo).Ignore()
                );
```

I've posted the thing on dontnetfiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/ZdpYM3 (note that you can't run it there because not all of the assemblies are loaded into the fiddle)

Comment: How does that address the question?

Answer (score -2):

Change your string concatenation code to produce something like:

```
EXEC someStoredProcedureName @p0,@p1,@p2,@p3,@p4,@p5,@p6,@p7
```

Comment: OP said that `EXEC someStoredProcedureName {0},{1},{2},{3},{4},{5},{6},{7}` does not work, so parameterizing it wouldn't work either.