# Generating table argument for stored proc accepting table-valued parameter

Tags: c#, entity-framework, stored-procedures, ef-code-first, table-valued-parameters

I'm calling a stored proc that takes table-valued parameter.

I know the following options for passing this parameter: create `DataTable`, `DbDataReader`, or `IList<SqlDataRecord>`.

I'm using `IList<SqlDataRecord>` (using `DataTable` is similar), but it involves writing tons of boilerplate code: create collection, set types of each the columns, add rows, set value of each cell.

I think that is exactly the type of code that Entity Framework is supposed to automate. So I hoped to define C# class matching SQL TVP type, add usual EF attributes, create collection of those objects and let EF implement `DbDataReader` or `IList<SqlDataRecord>` on top of my collection. But I cannot find any way to do it - e.g. there is `EntityDataReader`, but that's for reading from SQL - there is no implementation I can find that implements any of the suitable interfaces on top of in-memory collection.

Any suggestions, before I start writing it myself using Reflection?

Comment: Related to this question - check out my answer (basically I did the reflection bit + allowed for extra config): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8157345/entity-framework-stored-procedure-table-value-parameter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Entity Framework does not currently support table valued parameters. You can vote here for this feature: http://data.uservoice.com/forums/72025-ado-net-entity-framework-ef-feature-suggestions/suggestions/1015347-table-valued-parameters