# .Net List<int> as parameter for SQL stored procedure

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I would like to send a `List<int>` from my C# app as a parameter to a stored procedure in my SQL server database.

Are there any other way than parsing the `List<int>` in a string ? I tried with a User-Defined Table Type, but unfortunately entity framework doesn't support this type.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How are you executing the SP (EF, `DbCommand` or something else)?

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8157345/entity-framework-stored-procedure-table-value-parameter) might help

Comment: What t-sql type are you hoping to map the list to?

Comment: @Richard I'm using EF to exec the SP. First I import the model and then I just execute the function automatically created during import.

Comment: @cerhart The list will be mapped in a `WHERE something IN (MyList)`clause. Parsing it in a string works but it's ugly, slower and need T-SQL post processing.

Comment: Create a custom table type, then pass that as a parameter to your procedure. EF support is patchy, so I use SqlCommand to execute it directly passing the value as a parameter. You could wrap this into a model partial extension class to keep it all in one box.