# Insert dataset with EF and a storedprocedure

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

I'm using EF 5.

I have a working stored procedure which takes a dataset and inserts all the data into a table (its a simple merge type thing).

I've mapped the storedprocedure to my insert through the modelbrowsers "Stored procedure mapping" hoping it would "magically" work.

I thought this would actually insert the dataset when doing

```
db.mytable.AddRange(List<Entity>)
```

The problem is, that the Stored Procedure gets called, but with individual rows and not a Dataset.

How do I insert a Dataset through a storedprocedure using EF?

I've tried googling for it, but all i could come up with is how to return a dataset from an EF sp - but that's not what i'm looking for.

Thank you in advance.

## Update

I've followed the link Richard provided and found a "solution"

***Create extension method***

```
 public static void ExecuteStoreProcedure(this ObjectContext context, string storeProcName, params object[] parameters)
        {
            string command = "EXEC " + storeProcName + " @Table";

            context.ExecuteStoreCommand(command, parameters);
        }
```

where `@Table` is the parameter name that the SP takes for my dataset/datatable

***Then doing like so:***

```
 using (var db = new MyEntities())
            {
                var Table = new SqlParameter("Table", SqlDbType.Structured);
                Table.Value = agentList.ToDataTable();
                Table.TypeName = "dbo.MyDataSetType";

                var objectContext = ((IObjectContextAdapter)db).ObjectContext;
                objectContext.ExecuteStoreProcedure("dbo.p_storedproc",Table);                         
            }
```

where `Table` again is the parameter name and the `TypeName` is the Dataset/Datatable type-name used for the parameter in the stored procedure.

I'm not quite happy with this solution - It works, but I would like a more functional way of doing it (more "EF like").

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8157345/entity-framework-stored-procedure-table-value-parameter Looks like it might be relevant

Comment: Followed your link and came up with a solution - I'm not happy with it, but it works :)