# Entity framework 6.x doesn't add table valued parameter while adding in model

Tags: c#, entity-framework, stored-procedures

I'm trying to added stored procedure through Model browser, the SP had a table valued parameter. SP is added with function imports, But it's missing the table valued parameter. SP had 5 parameters including tvp, but i can see only 4 parameter and tvp parameter is missing.

I did googling to find the reason and solution. Everyone is suggesting to use entitie's ExecuteStoreProcedure method.
e.g. [Entity Framework Stored Procedure Table Value Parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8157345/entity-framework-stored-procedure-table-value-parameter)

But i want to use the function import which is created while we add SP using Model browser, all other SPs works well as they don't have tvp.
Note: using EF 6.1.1 and .net 4.5, and VS2013

Quetion: does C# and EF supports importing SP wtih TVP ?

Comment: Same problem here ! No answer unfortunately :'(

Comment: @Virus721 Well, no, it doesn't happen, so no it doesn't. Just add the code manually to a partial class extending the context.

Answer (score 1):

A github post was submitted regarding the issue, concerning EF core but applicable to EF 6 as well:

> - Stored procedures are only supported in raw/inline SQL in Entity    Framework Core.
> - Table Valued Parameters are only supported in raw/inline SQL in    Entity Framework Core because we just pass any SqlParameter through
>     to the underlying ADO.NET provider.
> - We initially used "Entity Framework 7" as the name for EF Core, but    there is no released product called "Entity Framework 7" so I am not
>     100% which product you are referring to.

Microsoft initial thought was to prepare EF 6 towards the new EF core standards, so they decided they will support the table valued parameters **only on raw/inline sql**.

You pass the `SqlParameter` to the underlying ado.net provider either way so there really is no reason to pass the param through `Functions Import`.

So yes, the way for you to go is to use `ExecuteStoreProcedure` as Microsoft is aptly prompting to do so, or just add the code yourself by extending the partial class with implementation of your own.