# ExecuteSqlCommand of EF always return -1

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, stored-procedures

```
        DbContext.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(sql, parameters)
```

I am using above method of Entity Framework to execute SP which takes table valued parameter and perform some operation.

It is successfully doing its task and I can see the result in the database. But it always return -1, no matter the query is successfully executed or not. I think, it should return 1 if the query execution is successful.

Could someone clarify me. Thanks

Comment: The return value of a stored-procedure is defined in the procedure itself. Please post the source code of the procedure.

Comment: Without seeing the stored procedure, we can't be sure why it is returning -1.

Comment: `ExecuteSqlCommand` returns the result returned by the database after executing the command. That is, if you expect a result you must return it from your sp. What are you returning from the store procedure?

Comment: store procedure does only select and insert operation, it does not return anything. I am thinking that, once the execution of sp is done successfully then ExecuteSqlCommand() will return 1 and if there is any issue while execution then it returns -1.

Answer (score -1):

EF does not support Table Valued Parameters. This [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8157345/entity-framework-stored-procedure-table-value-parameter) points however to an extension you could potentially use to achieve what you want. 
(Note I have not tried the extension so don't know whether it works well).

Comment: I am able to send table valued parameter in the sp by specifying SqlParameter parameter = new SqlParameter(paramName, table); 
    parameter.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Structured; 
    parameter.TypeName = typeName;  and the sp is executed and I am able to see the correct result in the database. But I was assuming that ExecuteSqlCommand() returns 1 or -1 based success or failure of query execution.