# entity framework calling store procedures with UDT

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, entity-framework

I have a problem when trying to create store procedures and calling it by .NET entity framework.

Firstly, in the SQL, a store procedure is created with inputs

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[AddNotice_OC]
    @OperatorName VARCHAR(32) = NULL,
    @ModuleCode VARCHAR(10) = NULL,
    @NoticeInfo udt_NoticeInfo READONLY,
    @Msg NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @NoticeId_oc BIGINT,
    @ReturnCode INT OUTPUT
AS
```

note that udt_NoticeInfo is user defined table of SQL

Then, in the .NET entity framework, i have an existing .edmx, i click in the Model Browser and perform Update Model from Database.

The store procedure can be found and added in the .edmx file, however the parameter of the udt_NoticeInfo is missing, the process simply the udt_NoticeInfo.

Thus, I want to know how can I correct the .edmx so that the udt_noticeInfo can be included in the model?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You **cannot pass table valued parameters** directly using Entity Framework.

Check this [link](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/78607b/using-table-valued-parameters-in-entity-framework/) and this [link](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Stored-Procedure-with-6c194514) and this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8157345/entity-framework-stored-procedure-table-value-parameter) for how to execute stored procs accepting Table Valued parameter  in EF.

It basically involves

1. creating a `DataTable` to hold the rows
2. adding datatable as `SqlParameter` with DbType as `SqlDbType.Structured`
3. executing the stored proc using `ObjectContext.ExecuteStoreCommand()`
   by passing the sql command and the parameters