# Entity Framework Core Linq query returning ids which do not exist in database

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I wonder if there is an easy way using Linq to SQL with Entity Framework Core to query check if a given list of ids exist in the database and which returns the list of ids that do not exist.

The use case I come across this is if the user can do something with a list of object (represented through the list of their ids) I want to check if these ids exist or not.

Of course I could query all objects/object ids that exist in the database and cross check in a second step.

Just wondering if it would be possible in one step.

What I mean in code:

```
public class MyDbObject 
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public IActionResult DoSomethingWithObjects([FromQuery]List<int> ids} 
{
    List<int> idsThatDoNotExistInTheDb = DbContext.MyDbObject.Where(???)

    return NotFound("those ids do not exist: " + string.Join(", ", idsThatDoNotExist));
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can obtain the list of IDs that match, then remove them from the original list, like this:

```
var validIds = DbContext
    .MyDbObject
    .Where(obj => ids.Contains(obj.Id))
    .Select(obj => obj.Id);
var idsThatDoNotExistInTheDb = ids.Except(validIds);
```

This approach may be slow, though, so you may be better off doing it in a stored procedure that takes a table-valued parameter ([how?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8157345/335858))

**Note:** Pre-checks of this kind are not bullet-proof, because a change may happen between the moment when you validate IDs and the moment when you start the operation. It is better to structure your APIs in a way that it validates and then does whatever it needs to do right away. If validation fails, the API returns a list of errors.

Comment: A question to your note. Any hint how I could restructure this? Let the use case be that I want to use the ids of MyDbObject in a m:n table between MyDbObject and MyDbObject2 and I wanted to avoid waiting for a DbUpdateException. Which would be raised recognizing that one of the foreign keys (in the m:n table) can't be set because one of the ids is missing. So I do this precheck and return an error or an InternalServerError if it got deleted in between. Haven't figured out how to solve this "perfectly".

Comment: Restructuring not necessarily using linq.

Comment: @monty There is nothing inherently wrong with catching `DbUpdateException`, except that it does not provide you with the list of IDs that failed validation. One approach to fixing this is to create a stored procedure that performs validation and does what you would like to do in a single transaction. This stored procedure would return a list of failing IDs, or an empty list if everything ran OK.

Comment: Works well. Thanks