# How to call stored procedure with table valued parameter from .net core Entity Framework

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, entity-framework-core

I have a stored procedure with table valued parameter.
I have to call it from Entity framework in .net core.

I couldn't find any API on context object.

I have tried with ADO.net API's and it worked but now I have to call it from EF in .net core. Stored procedure which I have to call returning result which I have to catch.

**My sample SP as below**

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetMyData] 
@MyRequest [dbo].[MyRequestType] Readonly
As 
BEGIN

--Its sample SP thats why returned request table as it is    
select * from @MyRequest


END
```

`MyRequestType` is User defined table type

its structure is as below

```
CREATE TYPE [dbo].[MyRequestType] AS TABLE(
    [Id] [numeric](22, 8) NULL,
    [Col1] [bigint] NULL,
    [Col2] [numeric](22, 8) NULL 
)
```

I am using Code first approach in EF core

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: if i understand your query i think this post can help you  : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8157345/entity-framework-stored-procedure-table-value-parameter

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50339420/9940803

Comment: and other post : https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/1033512/Executing-Stored-Procedure-with-User-Defined-Table

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Entity Framework Stored Procedure Table Value Parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8157345/entity-framework-stored-procedure-table-value-parameter)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Finally I could able to call Table values parameter Stored procedure from my .net core service which uses EF core

I have created fake Response Domain Model

```
   public class MyResponse
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int Col1{ get; set; }
        public int Col2 { get; set; } 
    }
```

I called it Fake Domain Model because Domain model is generally table representation in CLR class but I dont have such Table in SQL Server.

Then I have Added property for this under Context class as below

```
public class MyQueryDbContext : DbContext
{
  public virtual DbSet<MyResponse> Data { get; set; }
    .
    .
    .
}
```

Then Need to create Data Table for Request parameter list, I have added like below

```
 DataTable table = new DataTable();
 table.Columns.Add("Id", typeof(int));
 table.Columns.Add("Col1", typeof(int));
 table.Columns.Add("Col2", typeof(int));
```

Then I have called Stored procedure from .net core API using EF and passed datatable as parameter like below

```
 var parameter = new SqlParameter("@MyRequest", SqlDbType.Structured);
 parameter.Value = table;
 parameter.TypeName = "[dbo].[MyRequestType]" // My Table valued user defined type
var response=_context.Data
                     .FromSql("EXEC [dbo].[GetMyData] @MyRequest", parameter)
                     .ToList()
```

You will get response in you response variable.

Comment: I have one question, how do you prevent the migration to try to create the table every time you will modify the structure of the database and call Add-Migration ?

Comment: Add `modelBuilder.Entity<T>().HasNoKey().ToView(null);` to OnModelCreating method or `[Keyless]` decorator to the class, depending on the EF version you are running.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/keyless-entity-types?tabs=data-annotations

Answer (score 4):

Just an update for [ef core 3+](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-3.x/breaking-changes).

You can use either `FromSqlRaw` or `FromSqlInterpolated`.

```
var query = context.DnoFacts.FromSqlRaw("EXEC [dbo].[GetMyData] {0} ,{1}", otherParam, TableValueParameter) 


var query = context.DnoFacts.FromSqlInterpolated($"EXEC [dbo].[GetMyData] {otherParam}, {TableValueParameter}")
```

Comment: EF Core 6: `FromSqlInterpolated` does not have an argument for TableValueParameter.