# Oracle Entity Framework Core pass table parameter to stored procedure

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, .net-core, odp.net, ef-core-2.2

I am trying to pass a parameter to a stored procedure using the `Oracle.EntityFrameworkCore` package like this:

```
DataTable table = new DataTable();
table.Columns.Add("keyColumn", typeof(string));
table.Columns.Add("valueColumn", typeof(string));

var row = table.NewRow();
row.ItemArray = new object[]
{
    entry.KeyColumn,
    entry.ValueColumn
};

table.Rows.Add(row);

var parameter = new OracleParameter("entries",table);
parameter.UdtTypeName = "entry_type_list";


return context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommandAsync(
    new RawSqlString( @"EXEC set_entry_list (:entries)" ),
    parameter);
```

The stored procedure and type are defined like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE entry_type AS OBJECT
(
"keyColumn" NVARCHAR2(3), 
"valueColumn" NVARCHAR2(3)
);

CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE entry_type_list AS TABLE OF entry_type;

CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE set_entry_list (entries entry_type_list) AS
BEGIN
REM Doing stuff
END;
```

But I get an error:

> System.ArgumentException: Value does not fall within the expected range.
>   at Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleParameter..ctor(String parameterName, Object obj)

The only sources for this is [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54782689/how-to-call-stored-procedure-with-table-valued-parameter-from-net-core-entity-f) how to do this with SQL Server, but no answer for Oracle with EFCore. The issue here seems to be that Oracle only accepts an `OracleParameter` whereas others use `SqlParameter`.

If I use the `SqlParameter` type like this:

```
var parameter = new SqlParameter("entries", SqlDbType.Structured);
parameter.TypeName = "entry_type_list";
parameter.Value = table;
```

I get this error:

> System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter' to type 'Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleParameter'.

I also did try setting `parameter.OracleDbType` to different values like `Blob`, `RefCursor`, `Clob` or `XmlType`, setting `parameter.DbType` to `Object` or setting `CollectionType` to `PLSQLAssociativeArray` with no success. Also passing a list or an array of objects instead of a table did not succeed.

I currently have no idea what else I could try.

Any method to pass a big amount of entities to a stored procedure in a performant way would help. I use them with the merge-command so I need to be able to convert those parameters to a table.

Comment: `SqlParameter` is part of the  `SqlClient` library, which is for Microsoft **SQL Server** exclusively.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I now found a solution using a temporary table and using this one as my input parameter.

As I can't pass a complete table, but an array of simple objects I have to fill this table by passing one array for each column:

```
var keyColumn = new OracleParameter( "keyColumn", OracleDbType.Decimal );
keyColumn.Value = values.Select( c => c.KeyColumn).ToArray();
var valueColumn = new OracleParameter( "valueColumn", OracleDbType.Decimal );
valueColumn = values.Select( c => c.ValueColumn).ToArray();

using ( var transaction = this.dbContext.Database.BeginTransaction( IsolationLevel.ReadCommitted) )
{
    var connection = this.dbContext.Database.GetDbConnection() as OracleConnection;
    OracleCommand cmd = connection.CreateCommand();

    cmd.CommandText = @"
        INSERT INTO TMP_TABLE 
        (
        ""keyColumn"",
        ""valueColumn""
        )
        VALUES (
        :keyColumn,
        :valueColumn)";
    cmd.Parameters.Add( keyColumn ); 
    cmd.Parameters.Add( valueColumn );
    cmd.ArrayBindCount = values.Length;
    var insertCount = await cmd.ExecuteNonQueryAsync();


    cmd = connection.CreateCommand();
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    cmd.CommandText = "dbo.stored_procedure";

    var result = await cmd.ExecuteNonQueryAsync();
    transaction.Commit();
}
```

I created the temp table like this:

```
CREATE
GLOBAL TEMPORARY TABLE "dbo"."TMP_TABLE"
ON COMMIT DELETE ROWS
 AS SELECT * FROM "dbo"."REAL_TABLE" WHERE 0=1;
```

And changed my stored procedure to use it:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE stored_procedure AS 
BEGIN
    REM use the "dbo"."TMP_TABLE"
END;
```

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24413040/3085985) helped me with the approach of bulk inserting with one array per column. The thread also contains some further discussion about the topic and a more generic approach.

Comment: I have couple good answers on this subject. But yes, oracle works completely different from SQL server (client soft)

Comment: I'm a bit overwhelmed by the amount of answers you have. Do you have anything special in mind / do you think there is a better approach than what I did?