# Pass a String as Parameter Into _context.Database.SqlQuery ASP.NET MVC 5

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc

I have A controller

```
  public ActionResult Index(int[] eo){ employes = _context.Database.SqlQuery(select * from table where tableId IN (@p0),String.Join(",", eo))}
```

The problem is the data of `@p0` is being passed as string and TableID is int. The debug shows `@p0` as ('10,2,3,5') what I want is (10,2,3,5).

How I can handle this problem?

Comment: What type is `eo`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Entity Framework Stored Procedure Table Value Parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8157345/entity-framework-stored-procedure-table-value-parameter)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For SQL Server you can use JSON:

```
public ActionResult Index(int[] eo)
{ 
  var sql = @"
  select * 
  from table 
  where tableId IN (select value from openjson(@p0))
  ";

  var json = "[" + String.Join(",", eo) + "]";

  var employes = _context.Database.SqlQuery(sql,json).ToList();
}
```

Comment: thanks it worked but  i just want to know if i opened myself to SQL injection with this method .

Comment: Not with int[].  If it was string[] you’d need to worry.

Answer (score 0):

There are probably more elegant ways to solve this problem, but you can just split the string into a list of strings and parse each of them to int.

Something like this:

```
string test = "10,2,3,5";
List<string> stringList = test.Split(",").ToList();
List<int> intList = new List<int>();
foreach(string str in stringList)
{
    intList.Add(int.Parse(str));
}
```